# The meaning of the bold part in the mentioned text?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

A special form of this requirement is that the belief has been acquired in a reliable way. Thinking of a belief's being based on grounds, this would amount to the requirement that the belief be based on such grounds that forming beliefs like that on the basis of grounds like that is a generally reliable way of forming beliefs, **one that can be relied on provide mostly true beliefs**. ([Source](https://fphil.uniba.sk/fileadmin/fif/katedry_pracoviska/kfdf/Personal/Nuhlicek/Literatura/Teorie_zdovodnenia/Alston__W._P._-_Epistemic_Desiderata__1993_.pdf))

The bold part is unclear. Is it grammatically incorrect?

Comment: I believe so. I think it should be "one that can be relied on *to* provide mostly true beliefs. Is that what you were thinking?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a couple of typos in your example which make it not quite correct.

> one that can be relied on **to** provide mostly true beliefs
>   one that can be relied **upon to** provide mostly true beliefs